# Giving Access of Database to Unity plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have generated the sqlite db file in android app. I have a unity project which is being imported as aar file in that app. That Unity plugin/project cannot access the db file which is being generated in package-name/databases/database-filename. Please guide how can i give access of db to unity project which is imported in the same app. I have followed the following tutorial for making unity aar file.

https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

Comment: Sharing code, error messages, what you have tried would help in answering your query. Are you able to access the db in the android native app? Where is the db stored? How are you trying to access it in Unity?